# How to hide Label or TextBlock inside a WPF Grid

Tags: wpf, grid, label, textblock

I am trying to hide the TextBlock and Label which are placed inside a grid like so:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Hidden">Text inside TextBlock</TextBlock>
<Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Hidden">Text inside Label</Label>
```

But the text does not disappear. Any ideas why that is?

Comment: UPDATE: Damn, it does work when you run it, it was just the designer that does not display it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, it does work when you run it, it was just the designer that does not display it correctly.

Answer (score 15):

In Code you can use something like the following:

```
Label1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

Answer (score 9):

Try [Visibility.Collapsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility.aspx)

```
<TextBlock Visibility="Collapsed">
```

Answer (score 2):

@Laxman Singhare you sure about Visibility.Hidden? It should be

```
this.TextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Comment: Working solution!

Answer (score -2):

You could also set with and height == 0